# forward dynamic programming for shortest path

Tags: python

I want to ask how to make it as the shortest path for X to Y.For an example, X = 10 and Y = 22, it needs 2 operations ,which is +1 and *2 that (X+1)*2=Y

```
def main():
operations = ["+1","*2"]
X,Y = eval(input("Please enter two positive integers for X and Y, where X < Y, separated by a comma: "))
def XtoY(operations,X,Y):
    table = [None for x in range(Y+1)]
    for a in range(X+1):
        table[a] = [ ]
    for i in range(X+1,Y-X+1):
        for operation in operations:
            if X >= Y:
                continue
            if operation == "+1":
                b = i-1
                if table[b] != None:
                    table[i] = table[b][:]
                    table[i].append(operation)

            if operation == "*2":
                c = (i-1)*2
                if c > Y:
                    continue
                if table[b] != None:
                    table[c] = table[b][:]
                    table[c].append(operation)


    if table[-1] != None:
                                     print('The minimum number of operations to make '+str(X)+' equal to '+str(Y)+' is ' ,len(table[-1]))
                                     print('The sequence of operations is:')
                                     print('Y = ',table[-1])
    else:
                                     print('No solution possible')
XtoY(operations,X,Y)
```

main()

However,when I input 10 and 1000,it gives:`Please enter two positive integers for X and Y, where X < Y, separated by a comma: 10,1000
The minimum number of operations to make 10 equal to 1000 is  491
The sequence of operations is:
Y =  ['+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '+1', '*2']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X,Y = 10,1000
operations = ["+1","*2"]
def XtoY(operations,X,Y):
    steps_num = []
    steps = []
    steps_num.append(0)
    steps.append([])
    for i in range(X+1, Y+1):
        if i / 2 < X:
            steps_num.append(steps_num[-1] + 1)
            steps.append(list(steps[-1]) + ["+1"])
        elif i % 2 == 0 and steps_num[i / 2 - X] < steps_num[i - 1 - X]:
            steps_num.append(steps_num[i / 2 - X] + 1)
            steps.append(list(steps[i / 2 - X]) + ["*2"])
        else:
            steps_num.append(steps_num[-1] + 1)
            steps.append(steps[-1] + ["+1"])
    return steps[-1]

print XtoY(operations, X, Y)
```

use `steps_num` to record the least step num to reach value `i` from value `X`, use `steps` to record how to reach `i` from value `X`
we know:

- `steps_num[0] = 0 #from X to X`
- `steps[0] = [] #from X to X`

for every value `i`, between `X` and `Y`

- `steps_num[i - X] = steps_num[i - 1 - X] if i is odd`
- `steps_num[i - X] = steps_num[i - 1 - X] if i / 2 < X`
- `steps_num[i - X] = steps_num[i - 1 - X] if steps_num[i - 1 - X] < steps_num[i / 2 - X]`
- `steps_num[i - X]= steps_num[i / 2 - X] if steps_num[i - 1 -X] > steps_num[i / 2 - X]`

Comment: what is the implication behind i / 2 < X?

Comment: @tim if i / 2 < X, then the way to i can only be +1 from (X - 1), it's impossible to reach i by *2